# Using jQuery to delete all elements with a given id

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

I have a form with several spans with `id="myid"`. I'd like to be able to remove all elements with this id from the DOM, and I think jQuery is the best way to do it. I figured out how to use the `$.remove()` method to remove one instance of this id, by simply doing:

```
$('#myid').remove()
```

but of course that only removes the first instance of myid. How do I iterate over ALL instances of myid and remove them all? I thought the jQuery `$.each()` method might be the way, but I can't figure out the syntax to iterate over all instances of myid and remove them all.

If there's a clean way to do this with regular JS (not using jQuery) I'm open to that too. Maybe the problem is that id's are supposed to be unique (i.e. you're not supposed to have multiple elements with `id="myid"`)?

Comment: Try the snippet i posted below, it should work.

Comment: "all elements with a given id" hurts in my brain. ID's should be unique, everywhere.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`.remove()` should remove all of them. I think the problem is that you're using an ID. There's only supposed to be *one* HTML element with a particular ID on the page, so jQuery is optimizing and not searching for them all. Use a *class* instead.

Answer (score 46):

All your elements should have a unique IDs, so there should not be more than one element with #myid

An "id" is a unique identifier. Each time this attribute is used in a document it must have a different value. If you are using this attribute as a hook for style sheets it may be more appropriate to use classes (which group elements) than id (which are used to identify exactly one element).

Neverthless, try this:

```
$("span[id=myid]").remove();
```

Answer (score 14):

id of DOM element shout be unique. Use class instead (`<span class='myclass'>`).
To remove all span with this class:

```
$('.myclass').remove()
```

Answer (score 12):

if you want to remove all elements with matching ID parts, for example:

```
<span id='myID_123'>
<span id='myID_456'>
<span id='myID_789'>
```

try this:

```
$("span[id*=myID]").remove();
```

don't forget the '*' - this will remove them all at once - cheers

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bv6HJ/)

Answer (score 10):

The cleanest way to do it is by using html5 selectors api, specifically `querySelectorAll()`.

```
var contentToRemove = document.querySelectorAll("#myid");
$(contentToRemove).remove();
```

The `querySelectorAll()` function returns an array of dom elements matching a specific id.  Once you have assigned the returned array to a `var`, then you can pass it as an argument to jquery `remove()`.

Answer (score 6):

You should be using a `class` for multiple elements as an `id` is meant to be only a single element. To answer your question on the `.each()` syntax though, this is what it would look like:

```
$('#myID').each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Official jQuery documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Answer (score 0):

As already said, only **one** element can have a specific ID. Use classes instead. Here is jQuery-free version to remove the nodes:

```
var form = document.getElementById('your-form-id');
var spans = form.getElementsByTagName('span');

for(var i = spans.length; i--;) {
    var span = spans[i];
    if(span.className.match(/\btheclass\b/)) {
        span.parentNode.removeChild(span);
    }
}
```

`getElementsByTagName` [is the most cross-browser-compatible method](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#gettingelements) that can be used here. `getElementsByClassName` would be much better, but is not supported by Internet Explorer <= IE 8.

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/U7bgA/)