# Jquery remove all inputs with same class except one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, removechild

I want to remove all input labels with same class except one in div `#tikersDiv`.
I got this script but it doesn't work:

```
  $('#tikersDiv').children('label').each(function(i){
  let removed = $('#id_' + (++i)).children('label').each(function(){
     $(this).remove();
  });
  $(this).append($(removed[0]).html());
  $(this).append($(removed[3]).html());
});
```

Comment: Can't use class name? $('#tiketsDiv').children('.classname').remove(); https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223141/using-jquery-to-delete-all-elements-with-a-given-id

Comment: Ids _must_ be unique. Two elements _cannot_ share the same id. Use a class instead.

Comment: @이승현 I need to delete all duplicates, not with particular class. All inputs are added with php so there will be much more duplicates in future, all of them should be removed with one function.

Comment: @Andy I know. That's why I need to delete all duplicates. And yeas, I can select them with class , duplicates have identical class too

Comment: Then you should fix the output from your PHP so you don't have duplicate ids.

Comment: Also see: [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)  And the answer has changed since html5.

Comment: @Andy check my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've got this. If anybody want to remove all child elements with same class except one in div, just use this script. I hope I will help somebody

```
var classes = $('#tikersDiv label').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('class');
    }).get();

$.each(classes, function(value, index){
     $('#tikersDiv').find('.' + index + ':not(:eq(0))').remove();
     });
```